# Baking Jiggly Cheese cake in microwave oven convection mode

Tags: cheesecake

I am planning to try out this recipe..

http://renilskitchen.blogspot.com/2018/11/jiggly-fluffy-japanese-cheesecake.html?m=1

But the trouble is, it mentions changing the temperature midway through the process. I have a microwave oven(Samsung) with convection mode and I am not sure if it is possible to get this recipe right.. what  do you guys think ? Anyone with experience baking Jiggly cheese cakes? Specifically in a convection microwave ??

Answer (score 1):

This looks like quite a fussy recipe - the author says *Keys  for perfect Japanese souffle cheesecake is "meringue" and "oven temperature". After so many trials and errors, I present this cheesecake before you..*.  That's not to say you can't do it, but getting the results you want may take a couple of goes.

A good microwave oven convection mode is a reasonable imitation of a real oven (mine is Panasonic which should be comparable to Samsung) but the top heat can be a little fierce especially for tall things, which may be a further issue as you don't want to open the door.  This may actually be the hardest part to deal with.

Heating is quick enough to be comparable to a normal oven when you turn the temperature up.  Cooling may be a little quicker - you have less thermal mass and the insulation tends not to be as good as modern ovens.  Quoting from the recipe:

> bake on the lower rack of the preheated oven at 120 degree Celsius for
>   20 minutes
>
> then increase the temperature to 150 degree Celsius and
>   bake for 40 minutes
>
> now reduce heat to 120 degree Celsius and bake for
>   30 minutes
>
> now turn off the oven and keep this in the oven for 10
>   minutes
>
> *the temperature and timing may vary depending on oven*

(emphasis mine)

I'd expect the second 120°C period to be a little short - so maybe increase to 35 minutes (or perhaps even increase the length of the 150°C bit by 5 minutes).  If the cooling when you turn it off is a little quicker than expected it may not finish cooking in the middle.  One thing you can do to increase the thermal mass (i.e. make it change temperature more slowly) is to preheat and cook with a large lump of ceramic in there, for example a pizza stone or a couple of stoneware dinner plates.  This should reduce the cooling when you open the door to put the cheesecake in, reducing the amount the (top) element has to run, as well as slowing the change when you change the setpoint.